# Should applications do window management related tasks?

Tags: design-patterns, user-interface, operating-system, window

I was recently making changes to one of my company's applications, and due to a bug in Qt ([http://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-19207](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-19207)) we'll either need to postpone the release until Nokia fixes that issue, or disable fullscreen mode for Mac users until then.

But that got me wondering - is it really even necessary to have a fullscreen mode option for most applications? Obviously it's perfect for certain applications such as:

- Multimedia players (video/audio)
- Web browsers
- Office suites

But I don't really see the point for most other applications, including the one in question.  I've also seen a good number of Windows applications add an "always on top" menu, is this bad practice in general? On Linux, KDE and Gnome provide this for you and it does seem like something that should be done below the application level.

Should most applications really do any of their own window management at all? If the OS doesn't provide the functionality, what should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most of the cases they should not, unless the application is as you say browser, CAD, editor (paintshop, maya, max, etc.)

Here is a related answer: [How to make a window always stay on top in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683330/how-to-make-a-window-always-stay-on-top-in-net/683346#683346)

Directly to the point of top-most windows [Raymond Chen]: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx