# C# TopMost and Tray

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a WinForms application which shows a new small Form (with `TopMost` set to true) when a hotkey is pressed.

However when I send my main Form to the tray, the second Form is still displayed on the desktop.

How can I set my Form always to display on top of all applications, or just on top of the currently focused application?

Answer (score 1):

Reference: [Form.TopMost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/683346/1004522).

Form.TopMost will work unless the other program is creating topmost windows. There is no way to create a window that is not covered by new topmost windows of another process.

***"How do I create a window that is never covered by any other windows, not even other topmost windows?"*** 
Imagine Ans. if this were possible and imagine if two programs did this. Program A creates a window that is "super-topmost" and so does Program B. Now the user drags the two windows so that they overlap. What happens? You've created yourself a logical impossibility. One of those two windows must be above the other, contradicting the imaginary "super-topmost" feature.