# Is there a way to lock form's position in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to prevent a Windows Form from disappearing when losing focus? I want my form to stay locked at left of my screen, is there a way?

Comment: That sounds like horrendous and unbelievably annoying functionality. You're also asking about two different things.

Comment: you want to keep application topmost: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683330/how-to-make-a-window-always-stay-on-top-in-net

Comment: You should specify, in your title, tags, and question body, what platform you're using: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, etc. C# is a programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make the form `TopMost`
- Set the `StartupPosition` property to `Manual`
- Set both `Left` and `Top` properties to `0`.

Take a look at this reference too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/52aha046.aspx

Comment: What about multiple screens,Is this going to work as expected ?

Comment: @AviralSingh No, unless you consider the location of multiple screens, as you considered in your answer. But the question was considering **a** screen. If the developer has needed to set the position on multiple screens, he would need to specify which screen he wants to set the position before consider the multiple screens coding.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

```
YourForm.Topmost=true;
```

where **YourForm is your form's name**.This will make the window topmost.Set this property either using the designer or manually in the **Form Load event**.

To lock the window at the leftmost side on the screen set its location property as following;

```
this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
this.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y);
```

this makes sure the form remains at the leftmost side even if there are multiple monitors.