# C# prevent program from loosing focus

Tags: c#, security, locking, taskmanager

this is my first post so please do not kill me for dumb questions ;)

Atm I'm trying to create a "SecureLock" Application using a RFID Card Reader. Everything is working fine except the fact that it's not possible to prevent the Task Manager from showing up pressing ctrl-alt-del.

I "solved" that problem hiding the App-Lockscreen from the tast manager BUT my app loses focus when starting the task manager.

For security reasons it's not possible to disable the task manager from the ctrl-alt-del menu.

Has anyone an idea how to solve the focus problem?

Comment: Trying to do this in the way you've described is gimmicky, fake security. You should instead be looking into the [Windows Interactive Logon Architecture](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff404303(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: Yes it is, you're totally right... but completely adequate for my purposes. But thank you for that link, it's very interesting... maybe someday my knowledge is high enough for something like that :>

Comment: I don't believe it is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/a/683346/119527. You said you hid the program from Task Manager?  You might have hid it from the "Applications" tab, but certainly not from the "Processes" tab. Again, this is incredibly easy to get around.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing an application from ever losing focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503944/preventing-an-application-from-ever-losing-focus)

Comment: Surely it's hidden from the applications tab not the processes tab. As I said its completely adequate for my purposes. Thank you all, i'll have a look at Monika's link :) - Edit: okay, i've red the related articles, the "lock-form" is top-most already the problem is the taskbar poping up over the lock form while opening the taskmanager.