# Make a form to always stay on top of every window

Tags: c#

Is there a way to have my form staying on top of all other windows in C#, like in java with

```
setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the **TopMost** property:

```
this.TopMost = true;
```

You can set this property in code, like above.
This can be done using the designer as well:

[image: TopMost = true]

Note: Make sure to click the form once.

MSDN: [MSDN TopMost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.topmost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether a window appears in the topmost z-order.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost.aspx)

```
 this.TopMost = true;
```

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683330/how-to-make-a-window-always-stay-on-top-in-net

Comment: thanks man it turned out being just

    this.TopMost = true;