# How to open application in front?

Tags: c#

I have an application in Net 7 that open a window application, but if there is the file explorer open, for example, the file explorer keeps in front.

In my case I am trying to open the notepad with this code:

```
        ProcessStartInfo miProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        miProcessStartInfo.FileName = "Notepad.exe";
        miProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        miProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

Thanks.

Comment: you can use [SetWindowPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) and set TOPMOST

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475710/how-to-make-windows-always-on-top-application