# .NET | How to keep form on fullscreen game

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, directx, fullscreen

I googled some sites but can't find. I want to keep form on fullscreen game. I make gametool software and that feature is important. I need *VB.NET or C# example for this.

Thank you!

NOT: I saw that topic:[How to make a window always stay on top in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683330/how-to-make-a-window-always-stay-on-top-in-net). Bu the answer not work on games.

Comment: And you really couldn't find an example to full-screen a form?

Comment: Nope. You not understand me. I mean keep form top when game fullscreen mode is on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to HOOK into the game so you can render with the game (this is a pretty huge topic), unless the game is windowed, in that case you can just force the form to be the top window (Like the link in one of your comments explains).

Beware that this is considered an hack by most anti-cheat software (as it should..).

Things such as Steam are whiteflagged.

Comment: I was searched some websites and I see Directx hook contents. Maybe I need it. I will search about it. Thank you for answer.