# How to make a window always stay on top in .Net?(Task View)

Tags: c#, topmost

I have a security program for my schools. What i need,
I keep my Windows form up until I'm allowed to.
I can partially do with the following codes..

```
<code>
private static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
private const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
private const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
private const UInt32 TOPMOST_FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE;

[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

SetWindowPos(this.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);</code>
```

But
the above code.
Does not work in task view(windows 10)
[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAxhc.jpg)

Comment: WinForms has a TopMost property. Is that not enough?

Comment: I tried it unfortunately.

Comment: May not be possible, please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683330/how-to-make-a-window-always-stay-on-top-in-net) post, its accepted answer and the link provided in that answer.